# Asp.net MVC LINQ error message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using the ASP.NET Web-Api, I have the following POST setup in my controller. When posting to it from Fiddler, I get the error message:

```
The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

...when it gets to the var auth = dba.ApiMembers... line

```
    // POST api/Avail
    [BasicAuthentication]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostAvail(Avail[] avail)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Check if authorised
            var auth = dba.ApiMembers.Where(a => a.hotel_id == 
                   avail[0].HID && a.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this line?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/39adb1ac-451b-48cc-aac5-4c9fe82b7cce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ2SQL queries run in database, and it's not possible to translate `User.Identity.Name` and `avail[0]` into database commands. You should initialize those values as parameters and pass simple types to LINQ query.

```
var hid = avail[0].HID;
var userName = User.Identity.Name;
var auth = dba.ApiMembers.Where(a => a.hotel_id == hid && a.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
```